# Div tags displayed as tables not working how I expected

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a layout that has multiple tables that I'm trying to put in a much easier to read format than straight down the page. I need different sized cells per row so I'm using the div tag, but I also need the tables within the div tag to be vertically aligned so I'm using the display:table-cell style.

The problem I'm running into is that the first "table row" operates exactly as I'd like it to, but the second table row just smashes everything together to the left. I've made a quick JSFiddle to show what I'm talking about. What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/K8AJn/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="TR">
    <div class="TD" style="width:40%;">
    Info
    </div>

    <div class="TD" style="width:20%;">
    Some info
    </div>

    <div class="TD" style="width:40%;">
    More info
    </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="TR">
    <div class="TD" style="width:50%;">
    Info 1
    </div>

    <div class="TD" style="width:50%;">
    Info 2
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

**CSS:**

```
div.TR {
    background-color:blue;
    display: table-row;
}
div.TD {
    background-color:red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Why you are reinventing the wheel? Use `table` if it's *tabular data*

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The problem with table is that you can't have different sized table data cells and I was trying to prevent making a new table for each individual row. Each row within the page will have a different number of columns but I need them to spread across the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your table rows[sic] and cells don't have a point of reference.  Ordinarily they'd rely on the parent `table` to define their positioning.

To get your `TD`s to behave as expected, wrap the entire block of `TR`s in another `div`, with a class of `TABLE` and use the following:

```
.TABLE {
    display: table;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="TABLE">
    <div class="TR">
        <div class="TD" style="width:40%;height:300px;">Info</div>
        <div class="TD" style="width:20%;height:300px;">Some info</div>
        <div class="TD" style="width:40%;height:300px;">More info</div>
    </div>
    <div class="TR">
        <div class="TD" style="width:50%;height:300px;">Info 1</div>
        <div class="TD" style="width:50%;height:300px;">Info 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8AJn/4/)

It should be said, however, that this sort of approach to layout is only really appropriate for fringe cases.  There are much cleaner ways of achieving flexible layouts (and inline styles should be avoided like *the plague*).

Comment: In your fiddle though it's now changed the size of my data cells in row 1. That's the problem I'm running into. The only other thing I can think of is scrapping the div tags and creating a containing table for each individual row. I just didn't want to clutter the page with tons of table tags.

Comment: That's how tables behave.  The `td` with the greatest width defines the width of all other `td`s in the column

Comment: If you want them to be distinct, just use regular inline-block divs with percentage widths (or define another *table* wrapper for the second block of containers)

Comment: I'll do that. I was trying not to clutter the PHP with a bunch of table tags, but it seems the more I go down this route the more I'm cluttering it with div tags and styles. Thanks for the help.